# javascript get style from style element and replace with another style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a style element that dynamically renders the styles so i have:

```
<style>
    #DIV011b9769a89ae14b5bbe30616d77e9a09d
    { 
      padding-left:30px;
      padding-right:30px;
      padding-top:30px;padding- 
      bottom:30px;
      width:100%;
      background-color:#bc3333; 
    }
    @media(min - width: 600px) and(max - width: 960px){
        #DIV011b9769a89ae14b5bbe30616d77e9a09d
        { }
    }
    @media(min - width: 480px) and(max - width: 600px){
        #DIV011b9769a89ae14b5bbe30616d77e9a09d
        { }
    }
    @media screen and(max - width: 480px){
        #DIV011b9769a89ae14b5bbe30616d77e9a09d
        { }
    }
    #DIV011b9769a89ae14b5bbe30616d77e9a09d: hover
    { }
    @media(min - width: 600px) and(max - width: 960px){
        #DIV011b9769a89ae14b5bbe30616d77e9a09d: hover
        { }
    }
    @media(min - width: 480px) and(max - width: 600px){
        #DIV011b9769a89ae14b5bbe30616d77e9a09d: hover
        { }
    }
    @media screen and(max - width: 480px){
        #DIV011b9769a89ae14b5bbe30616d77e9a09d: hover
        { }
    }
    </style>
```

What i need to do is replace the whole of the first style which is #DIV011b9769a89ae14b5bbe30616d77e9a09d
to padding:0px;

I also need to replace #DIV011b9769a89ae14b5bbe30616d77e9a09d: hover { }, when i add new styles dynmaically

Also if the style in the media query changes i need to replace the styles in the media query for the element if teh style for this id #DIV011b9769a89ae14b5bbe30616d77e9a09d changes .

The #DIV011b9769a89ae14b5bbe30616d77e9a09d is the indicator to say replace this style with another new style.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: The contents of the `<style>` tag is just a string.  You can change it however you want with JavaScript.

Comment: i was thinking string manipulation, because i want to change part of the styles in the style element.